# Why there is no hasOne relationship in castle activerecord in contrast to Ruby on Rails?

Tags: castle-activerecord

or how can i represent an address to country mapping where an address has one one country in castle activerecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[BelongsTo]` attribute is there for one-to-one relations.

[http://api.castleproject.org/html/T_Castle_ActiveRecord_BelongsToAttribute.htm](http://docs.castleproject.org/Active%20Record.Relations%20Mapping.ashx#BelongsTo_2)